# Rails undefined method but method exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Maybe I've been staring at this code for too long, but what I'm doing seems trivial, yet my code still isn't working.

I'm using a modal to submit parameters to a controller, which should PATCH the Object, but instead, I'm getting `undefined method 'ignore_reason=' for nil:NilClass`.

**the modal**

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="deferHostModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deferHostLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="deferHostLabel">Defer a Host</h4>
      </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Defering a host means that you're choosing to ignore the security risks that Neo has identified for the given host.
              This host will be ignored from future security score calculations.  By filling in the information below, you will defer risk for the host for 30 days.</p>
            <br/>
            <%= form_for @network_host, url: {controller: "network_hosts", action: "defer_host"} do |f| %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :id, class: "form-control", required: "required" %>
              <%= f.label :ignore_reason, "Defer Reason" %>
              <%= f.text_area :ignore_reason, class: "form-control", required: "required" %>
              <br/>
              <%= f.label :ignore_name, "Your Name" %>
              <%= f.text_field :ignore_name, class: "form-control", required: "required" %>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary btn-success" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Which submits to the `controllers/network_hosts` method `defer_host`:**

```html
def defer_host
    @network_host = NetworkHost.where(id: params[:id]).first
    @network_host.ignore_reason = params[:ignore_reason]
    @network_host.ignore_name = params[:ignore_name]
    @network_host.ignore_flag = true
    @network_host.ignore_date = 30.days.from_now
    @network_host.save

    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

I've restarted my Rails server after the latest migration which added the `ignore_reason`, `ignore_name`, `ignore_date`, `ignore_flag`.

A sample Rails Console output of a `NetworkHost` to confirm that the fields are there to write to:

```html
#<NetworkHost id: 76, location_id: 14, mac_address: "D0:63:B4:00:5B:40", ip_address: "10.10.10.106", hostname: "OpenELEC", created_at: "2016-02-19 01:03:24", updated_at: "2016-04-14 19:30:21", deleted_at: nil, os_vendor: "Unknown", nickname: nil, vendor: "Unknown", os: "Unknown", ignore_reason: nil, ignore_name: nil, ignore_date: nil, ignore_flag: nil>
```

Also, to confirm that the parameters are being passed, on the Rails Error page (which shows the undefined method error), the parameters are at the bottom:

```html
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"a7kB1fDirzJFtRR2hBVt/64Z02ufxMzTfpZgKJoWSFI=",
 "network_host"=>{"id"=>"76",
 "ignore_reason"=>"test defer",
 "ignore_name"=>"JF"},
 "commit"=>"Save changes"}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your `@network_host` in controller is `nil` cause `id` key nested in `network_host` (according to your params).

```
params[:id]
#=> nil
NetworkHost.where(id: params[:id]).first
#=> nil
params[:network_host][:id]
#=> "76"
```

Try:

```
@network_host = NetworkHost.where(id: params[:network_host][:id]).first
#=> #<NetworkHost id: 76, location_id: 14, mac_address: "D0:63:B4:00:5B:40", ....>
```

Comment: Damn those nested parameters!  Thanks @ilya

Answer (score 2):

You're reading the error message wrong. The problem isn't that the method is undefined -- the problem is that you got a `nil` object.

When you call `.first` on a query with no result, you get `nil`; if you want to throw an exception if the object doesn't exist (hint: you do, most often), use `NetworkHost.find(id)`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the strong parameter list in the controller. I neglected to add the attribute to it. So when I went to create or edit the object, it wouldn't let me.